# yepnope.js - problem with scripts on same page

Tags: jquery, yii, modernizr, yepnope

I included yepnope.js and then the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/*<![CDATA[*/
    yepnope([{
      load: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js',
      complete: function () {
        if (!window.jQuery) {
          yepnope('local/jquery.min.js');
        } ...
```

However, while jquery is loading from the cdn, the following script at the end of the page is showing an error:

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('#Project_projectDateStart').datepicker({'dateFormat...
```

the error is **jQuery is not defined**

I have no option but to load the script at the end (loaded with Yii datepicker in this instance).

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Simple solution - see my blog post [Here](http://scott.donnel.ly/yepnope-jquery-document-ready/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use yepnope, you need to use callback functions. You cannot directly call jQuery since it is loaded asynchronously. It's a little difficult to parse the documentation on [yepnopejs.com](http://yepnopejs.com/) but that's the gist of it.

Basically, none of Yii's default AJAX and other JS helpers are going to work with yenope, from what I can tell. Or if they do work, it will be because Yii included another copy of jQuery in addition to the yepnope async loaded on from Google. You will probably need to do a bunch of work modifying the way Yii loads scripts to get it work correctly with an asynchronous loader like yepnope.

Good luck though! Async loaders are great for page performance, I use the Facebook one all the time.

Comment: thanks for that. I wonder if the Yii js was inserted by way of separate file and not at POS_END would that make any difference. Will keep looking.

Comment: Regardless of where the Yii JS is inserted (the include files are in the HEAD and the binds are in the END usually), Yii calls jQuery (or $) directly, and the way yepnope works you cannot do that since jQuery is only loaded in that async namespace. You will have to do a pretty serious rewrite of the Yii script manager to use yepnope I think. Cheers!